# Flutter nested object snapshot always empty

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter object that looks like this :

```
{
    "id": "4068",
    "ProfilePic": "https://osp.vvvvv.com/media/profile/OSP1572847746_424193.jpeg",
    "registration": [
        {
            "reg_no": "6574",
            "cadre": "KEN",
            "cadre_text": "KENYA ENROLLED NURSE"
        },
        {
            "reg_no": "4947",
            "cadre": "KEM",
            "cadre_text": "KENYA ENROLLED MIDWIFE"
        },
        {
            "reg_no": "1004",
            "cadre": "KECHN (PB)",
            "cadre_text": "KENYA ENROLLED  COMMUNITY HEALTH NURSE [PB]"
        }
    ]
}
```

It contains some nested contents. I have created a model and I am trying to retrieve data and display it in a component. My snapshot.data is always empty, but i can retrieve the data that is not nested. This is how my component looks like :

```
late Future<List<Registration>> _cadre;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: new FutureBuilder<List<Registration>>(
            future: _cadre,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData == false || snapshot.data == null) {
                return Text('Loading...');
              } else {
                List<Registration>? allCadres = snapshot.data;
                print(allCadres);
                return new ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        
                          Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              16.width,
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text((allCadres![index].cadreText).toString(),
                                      style: boldTextStyle(size: 12, color: mlColorRed)),
                                ],
                              ).expand()
                            ],
                          ).paddingBottom(16.0),
                                  
                      )          
                    }
                );
              }
            }));
  }

  //function that returns user cadres
  Future<List<Registration>> getCadres() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('https://xxx.co.ke/api/auth/user');
    var idNo = Globals.idNumber;
    var indexNo = Globals.indexNo;

    var response = await http
        .post(url, body: {"IdNumber": '$idNo', "IndexNo": '$indexNo'});
    return List<Registration>.from(json.decode(response.body).map((x) => Registration.fromJson(x)));
  }
```

This is how my models looks:

```
class Profile {
    Profile({
        this.id,
        required this.registration,
    });

    String? id;
    List<Registration> registration;

    factory Profile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Profile(
        id: json["id"],
        registration: List<Registration>.from(json["registration"].map((x) => Registration.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "registration": List<dynamic>.from(registration.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Registration {
    Registration({
        required this.regNo,
    });

    String regNo;

    factory Registration.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Registration(
        regNo: json["reg_no"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "reg_no": regNo,
    };

}
```

Any advise on how to rerieve the registration registration data will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try "itemcount" because without item count listView.builder wont work